# Products are not added to the general product list when using the React Query cash

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-query, tanstackreact-query, tanstack

I need to add a new product to a list using a React Query cash. The new entity does not come from the server, so I use setQueryData to manually update it from what comes from the mutating function. When I add a new product with the same id, each product is added correctly, but the ids are the same. But when I add a function to change the id, the product is added only once, no matter how much I add it to the list. The Id is stored as a state in the context, I think the problem is due to the fact that different IDs come to different parts of the component, because React Query does additional re-renders, but I can’t figure out how to solve this problem. I will be grateful for your help

```
const AddProduct = () => {
  const { data: categories } = useCategories();
  const { mutate, mutateAsync } = usePostProduct();
  const {id, updateId} = useId();


  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitSuccessful },
    reset,
    
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });



  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<TProductWithoutId> = async (
    data: TProductWithoutId
  ) => {
       mutate({id, ...data});
       updateId()
  };
```

```
export const usePostProduct = (id: number) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const { data: products } = useProducts(id);

  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (newProduct: TProduct) => postProduct(newProduct),
    onSuccess: (product: TProduct | undefined) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData(["products", { id }], () => {
        if (product && products) {
          console.log([...products, product])
          return [...products, product];
        }
        return products;
      });
    }

  });

  return mutation;
};
```

```
export const useProducts = (id?:number) => {
  const queryKey = id ? ['products', {id}] : ['products'];
  const query = useQuery(queryKey, fetchProducts);

  return query;
};
```

I tried the Id increase function and put it in OnSettled so that the Id changes after all the mutations. I tried placing the mutate function in Promise in onSubmit, and then executing the ID change function in then. But this did not give results